# core 2.0 bundling - how to not bundle during debug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, bundling-and-minification

I've added the BundlerHtmlHelper.cs file to my project from here:
https://gist.github.com/mohamedmansour/cd50123f8575daba7a7f12847b12da5d

and removed "Configs/" from line 32, as my bundleconfig.json is in the project root directory.

As an added difficulty, my bundled css and javascript files are not in wwwroot, they are in a different directory called root_content.

The files get bundled/minified properly when I'm not running bundler helper, but when I run it, I can see that the individual files are being requested in my browser under a t/css directory but they cannot be found.

I'm guessing from glancing at the code that BundlerHtmlHelper doesn't actually do anything with the original files, so they would need to actually reside in the wwwroot directory to begin with to work, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Decided I will modify the BundleHtmlHelper.cs file to copy the files from outside directories when needed.